# Why is the audio of my MacBook is becoming scratchy?

Tags: macbook-pro, audio

Okay, this is very weird. I've a MacBook Pro Retina 2014 model. It's all going very well. Sadly I've to use it in a dusty area most of the time. I've noticed the quality of the audio (any sound, iTunes, YouTube, etc) is getting really really worse gradually. Lots of buzzing and screeching and it's not as loud anymore!

I usually clean it by vacuuming around the keys and under the screen. I did look up some results online and couldn't find anything useful! 
Any help?

Comment: Based on what you're describing, I don't find the symptoms weird at all.
A vacuum cleaner creates static electricity that can potentially damage sensitive electronic components so this can actually make things worse. The safer way is to use a can of compressed air to remove particles, but not on speakers or microphones.
Is there a good reason to why you use the computer in a dusty area? If it's got something to do with special work environments thus is unavoidable, could you consider investing into some kind of protective sleeve to keep the dust out?

Comment: I do actually use a protective sleeve. my house is very dusty. Like in 3 hours of idleness the screen would be almost fully covered in dust. I noticed some keys on the keyboard are also a bit sludgy; this gets better after using the vacuum. Will resetting my SMC help?

Comment: Well, trying won't hurt, SMC reset is a quick thing to do. But if the environment and/or static electricity has caused damage to the components, software-based repair tricks won't help. By what you describe, it does sound a lot like physical wear. Computers are made to be used in clean areas. Your environment sounds like the computer should have a protective sleeve that bags the entire device inside of it, a bit like an underwater diving sleeve for cameras.

Comment: So for now what I can do about my audio is to replace the speakers? I'll pay more attention to dust from now on. I tried resetting SMC doesn't work!

Comment: Possibly so. Unless you're handy, having a professional supply new components and do the work of changing the speakers and possibly also some components inside might end up being a wasteful and expensive procedure on the long run; If your computer has been in an inappropriate environment, the speakers might just be the *first* components to start displaying the wear, and problems with other components would be quite likely to start occurring soon after.

Comment: The user manual of every electronic device states points regarding what kind of environments the device is built to be used in in order to last for the time that the manufacturer can guarantee. Neglect of those issues might end up shortening the lifespan of your current computer significantly, but with your next one, please read the manufacturer's care instructions and protect your computer appropriately, starting from the first day, and sticking to it.

Answer (score 1):

A vacuum cleaner can damage the small cones attached to the magnetic cone of a dynamic speaker, like in your MacBook Pro.  Similarly, a can of compressed air can damage the diaphragm.  One reason for buzzy, distorted sound is damage to these speaker components.

https://www.ifixit.com/Store/Mac/MacBook-Pro-15%22-Retina-Mid-2014

The above iFixit website (with whom I have no affiliation) describes how to tear down your Macbook Pro to see if your speakers are damaged.  They also sell replacement speakers.